# Using RequireJs with custom JS plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I'm trying to reference a test Jquery plugin from a requireJS module but it seems to not be working for some reason.

I go like so:
Here is my custom plugin:

**test.js**

```
$.fn.testfunction = function(){
     alert();
};
```

And where I'm referencing it from

**effects.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'step1', 'global', 'test'], function($, step1, global, test){     
    $('body').test();       
});
```

And finally my main.js where effects.js is loaded

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    urlArgs: "" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
    paths:
    {

            jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
            topJs: '/holoweb/static/js/v3_landing_top',
            bottom: '/holoweb/static/js/v3_landing_bottom',
            global: '/v2/js/variables/global',
            registeringUser: '/v2/js/registeringUser',
            effects: '/v2/js/effects/effects',
            step1: '/v2/js/variables/step1',
            test: '/v2/js/effects/test',
    }
});

require(['jquery']);
require(['bottom']);
require(['topJs']);

require(['effects']);


require(['registeringUser'], function(Registration){
    var NewUser = Registration.CreateNewUser;
    NewUser.startStep(1); 
});
```

When I go to view it, I get an error from chrome developer tools showing:
[http://i.imgur.com/IdSZPgh.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DyNb.png)

and I have no clue why.

Excuse any bad practices, im quite new to requirejs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

test.js has jquery as dependency. Replace it to:

```
define(['jquery'], function($){   
    $.fn.testfunction = function(){
        alert();
    };
}
```

Also you define `testfunction` function but call `test` function.

Replace `$('body').test();` to `$('body').testfunction();`

And you don't need use several `require` functions. There must be only 1 require function that will be entry point of your application.